# How to implement assignment operator in c# or what is alternative approach?

Tags: c#, assignment-operator

I am looking to find a good way to skip copy constructor approach in C# and looking for a way to do same thing with assignment in code below:

```
class Person
{
    string Name;
    int Age;
    public Person() { }
    //public Person(Person p)//copy contructor
    //{
    //    this.Name = p.Name;
    //    this.Age = p.Age;
    //}
    public Person(string name ,int age)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
    public void Set(string name,int age)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
    public void Get()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}",Name,Age);
    }
};

        Person person= new Person("Arif",40);
        person.Get();
        //Person person2 = new Person(person);//skip copy
        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2 = person;//use assignment
        person2.Get();
        person.Set("Mahmood",44);
        person.Get();
        person2.Get();
```

Output I see in case of copy when copy constructor is implemented is desired one given below

```
Arif  40
Arif  40
Mahmood  44
Arif  40
```

But output which I see for assignment is wrong one given below

```
Arif  40
Arif  40
Mahmood  44
Mahmood  44
```

How to get right output?

Comment: You can try writing C++ in C# but you really shouldn't. We don't do Copy constructors, and you cannot override assignment.

Comment: In essence person and person2 point to the same place, if you want to clone the object, well that is a different thing

Comment: Java and C# differ from C++ in that they do not deep clone (i.e. invoke a copy constructor) on assignment. They simply assign shallow references.

Comment: Are you sure this is a real problem?  `Person` is a domain entity with a strong identity and you should avoid clones as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If we go solely by the example you provided, you need Person to be a 'structure'. They are assigned by copying a value rather than refference.

Comment: You wouldn't want to make this kind of decision based solely on assignment however. The fundamental question is really about whether `Person`s are value-like. If you have two `Person`s with identical fields, are they really then the same "thing"?

Comment: Absolutely. But since the question is about technical detail only, so was my answer.

Comment: No, the question is written by someone clearly used to writing C++ who isn't trying to learn the nuances of writing C#. They're making fundamental mistakes and, if the took your advice, they would only be perpetuating their mistakes. There is no "technical detail", just flawed thinking.

Comment: Yes, and that part is reflected by 'If we go solely by the example you provided', which translates to 'there is probably a bigger picture to your question, but that is up to you to judge'.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the operator "=" in C#
[See here in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators)

> =, ., ?:, ??, ->, =>, f(x), as, checked, unchecked, default, delegate, is, new, sizeof, typeof  =======> These operators cannot be overloaded

Moreover, assignments that deny the normal behaviour are confusing

```
person1 = person2; //Your Person class
county1 = country2; // Some other class
```

Both are instances of classes (Person & Country) and therefore referenced. Why does Person behave other than Country?!?

The copy constructor is the option to go here if you are using classes.
A way to use the assignment operator is to use non-referenced types like primitives or a struct. However, a struct should not have functions! That's what classes are for.